# Spark Strutured Streaming automatically converts timestamp to local time

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-structured-streaming

I have my timestamp in UTC and ISO8601, but using Structured Streaming, it gets automatically converted into the local time. Is there a way to stop this conversion? I would like to have it in UTC.

I'm reading json data from Kafka and then parsing them using the `from_json` Spark function.

Input:

```
{"Timestamp":"2015-01-01T00:00:06.222Z"}
```

Flow:

```
SparkSession
  .builder()
  .master("local[*]")
  .appName("my-app")
  .getOrCreate()
  .readStream()
  .format("kafka")
  ... //some magic
  .writeStream()
  .format("console")
  .start()
  .awaitTermination();
```

Schema:

```
StructType schema = DataTypes.createStructType(new StructField[] {
        DataTypes.createStructField("Timestamp", DataTypes.TimestampType, true),});
```

Output:

```
+--------------------+
|           Timestamp|
+--------------------+
|2015-01-01 01:00:...|
|2015-01-01 01:00:...|
+--------------------+
```

As you can see, the hour has incremented by itself.

PS: I tried to experiment with the `from_utc_timestamp` Spark function, but no luck.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

For me it worked to use:

```
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.session.timeZone", "UTC")
```

It tells the spark SQL to use UTC as a default timezone for timestamps. I used it in spark SQL for example:

```
select *, cast('2017-01-01 10:10:10' as timestamp) from someTable
```

I know it does not work in 2.0.1. but works in Spark 2.2. I used in `SQLTransformer` also and it worked.

I am not sure about streaming though.

Comment: Just to be clear, without changing `spark.sql.session.timeZone`, does Spark convert timestamps (without timezone) to my local time zone and store converted timestamp when importing from a CSV, or does it do the conversion only when I run a `select` and write the results to console (or Kafka etc)?

Comment: How can I set it to local time? Whatever I try its giving me UTC. The question i posted -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58143743/how-to-get-the-current-local-time-or-system-time-in-spark-scala-dataframe/58143801#58143801 Please Help me with this.

Comment: isn't default value of  `spark.sql.session.timeZone` is UTC?

Answer (score 21):

**Note**:

This answer is useful *primarily* in Spark < 2.2. For newer Spark version see [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48769311/6910411) by [astro-asz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3005989/astro-asz)

However we should note that as of Spark 2.4.0, `spark.sql.session.timeZone` doesn't set `user.timezone` (`java.util.TimeZone.getDefault`). So setting `spark.sql.session.timeZone` alone can result in rather awkward situation where SQL and non-SQL components use different timezone settings.

Therefore I still recommend setting `user.timezone` explicitly, even if `spark.sql.session.timeZone` is set.

**TL;DR** Unfortunately this is how Spark handles timestamps right now and there is really no built-in alternative, other than operating on epoch time directly, without using date/time utilities.

You can an insightful discussion on the Spark developers list: [SQL TIMESTAMP semantics vs. SPARK-18350](http://apache-spark-developers-list.1001551.n3.nabble.com/SQL-TIMESTAMP-semantics-vs-SPARK-18350-td21621.html)

The cleanest workaround I've found so far is to set `-Duser.timezone` to `UTC` for both the driver and executors. For example with submit:

```
bin/spark-shell --conf "spark.driver.extraJavaOptions=-Duser.timezone=UTC" \
                --conf "spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=-Duser.timezone=UTC"
```

or by adjusting configuration files (`spark-defaults.conf`):

```
spark.driver.extraJavaOptions      -Duser.timezone=UTC
spark.executor.extraJavaOptions    -Duser.timezone=UTC
```

Comment: I would also add that if you want to use other time zones, you can't use `+` or `-` with UTC (like UTC+2, UTC-1), but it works with GMT (GMT+2, GMT-1 works).

Answer (score 0):

Although  two very good answers have been provided, I found them both to be a bit of a heavy hammer to solve the problem.  I did not want anything that would require modifying time zone parsing behavior across the whole app, or an approach that would alter the default time zone of my JVM.   I did find a solution after much pain, which I will share below...

**Parsing time[/date] strings into timestamps for date manipulations, then correctly rendering the result back**

First, let's address the issue of how to get Spark SQL to correctly parse a date[/time] string (given a format) into a timetamp and then properly render that timestamp back out so it shows the same date[/time] as the original string input.  The general  approach is:

```
- convert a date[/time] string to time stamp [via to_timestamp]
    [ to_timestamp  seems to assume the date[/time] string represents a time relative to UTC (GMT time zone) ]
- relativize that timestamp to the timezone we are in via from_utc_timestamp
```

The test code below implements this approach. 'timezone we are in'  is passed as the first argument to the timeTricks method.  The code converts the input string "1970-01-01" to localizedTimeStamp (via  from_utc_timestamp)  and verifies that  the 'valueOf' of that time stamp is the same as "1970-01-01 00:00:00".

```
object TimeTravails {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
    import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

    val spark: SparkSession = SparkSession.builder()
      .master("local[3]")
      .appName("SparkByExample")
      .getOrCreate()

    spark.sparkContext.setLogLevel("ERROR")

    import spark.implicits._
    import java.sql.Timestamp

    def timeTricks(timezone: String): Unit =  {
      val df2 = List("1970-01-01").toDF("timestr"). // can use to_timestamp even without time parts !
        withColumn("timestamp", to_timestamp('timestr, "yyyy-MM-dd")).
        withColumn("localizedTimestamp", from_utc_timestamp('timestamp, timezone)).
        withColumn("weekday", date_format($"localizedTimestamp", "EEEE"))
      val row = df2.first()
      println("with timezone: " + timezone)
      df2.show()
      val (timestamp, weekday) = (row.getAs[Timestamp]("localizedTimestamp"), row.getAs[String]("weekday"))

      timezone match {
        case "UTC" =>
          assert(timestamp ==  Timestamp.valueOf("1970-01-01 00:00:00")  && weekday == "Thursday")
        case "PST" | "GMT-8" | "America/Los_Angeles"  =>
          assert(timestamp ==  Timestamp.valueOf("1969-12-31 16:00:00")  && weekday == "Wednesday")
        case  "Asia/Tokyo" =>
          assert(timestamp ==  Timestamp.valueOf("1970-01-01 09:00:00")  && weekday == "Thursday")
      }
    }

    timeTricks("UTC")
    timeTricks("PST")
    timeTricks("GMT-8")
    timeTricks("Asia/Tokyo")
    timeTricks("America/Los_Angeles")
  }
}
```

**Solution to problem of Structured Streaming Interpreting incoming date[/time] strings as UTC (not local time)**

The code below illustrates how to apply the above tricks (with a slight modification) so as to correct  the problem of timestamps being shifted by the offset  between local time and GMT.

```
object Struct {
  import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
  import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    val timezone = "PST"

    val spark: SparkSession = SparkSession.builder()
      .master("local[3]")
      .appName("SparkByExample")
      .getOrCreate()

    spark.sparkContext.setLogLevel("ERROR")

    val df = spark.readStream
      .format("socket")
      .option("host", "localhost")
      .option("port", "9999")
      .load()

    import spark.implicits._


    val splitDf = df.select(split(df("value"), " ").as("arr")).
      select($"arr" (0).as("tsString"), $"arr" (1).as("count")).
      withColumn("timestamp", to_timestamp($"tsString", "yyyy-MM-dd"))
    val grouped = splitDf.groupBy(window($"timestamp", "1 day", "1 day").as("date_window")).count()

    val tunedForDisplay =
      grouped.
        withColumn("windowStart", to_utc_timestamp($"date_window.start", timezone)).
        withColumn("windowEnd", to_utc_timestamp($"date_window.end", timezone))

    tunedForDisplay.writeStream
      .format("console")
      .outputMode("update")
      .option("truncate", false)
      .start()
      .awaitTermination()
  }
}
```

The code requires input be fed via socket...  I use the program 'nc' (net cat) started like this:

```
nc -l 9999
```

Then I start the Spark program and provide net cat with one line of input:

```
1970-01-01 4
```

The output I get illustrates the problem with the offset shift:

```
-------------------------------------------
Batch: 1
-------------------------------------------
+------------------------------------------+-----+-------------------+-------------------+
|date_window                               |count|windowStart        |windowEnd          |
+------------------------------------------+-----+-------------------+-------------------+
|[1969-12-31 16:00:00, 1970-01-01 16:00:00]|1    |1970-01-01 00:00:00|1970-01-02 00:00:00|
+------------------------------------------+-----+-------------------+-------------------+
```

Note that the start and end for date_window is shifted by eight hours from the input (because I am in the GMT-7/8 timezone, PST).  However, I correct this shift using to_utc_timestamp to get the proper start and end date times for the one day window that subsumes the input: 1970-01-01 00:00:00,1970-01-02 00:00:00.

Note that in the first block of code presented we used from_utc_timestamp, whereas for the structured streaming solution we used to_utc_timestamp.  I have yet to figure out which of these two to use in a given situation.  (Please clue me in if you know!).

Answer (score 0):

Another solution that worked for me, was to set the jvm default timezone to your target timezone (UTC in your case).

```
TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
```

I added above code before writing my spark dataframe to database.

Answer (score 0):

If session timezone is not UTC then all these functions are converting to session timezone:

```
   from_unixtime(1695773049) 
   timestamp('1970-01-01 00:00:00.0 UTC') 
   cast('1970-01-01 00:00:00.0 UTC' as timestamp)
   current_timestamp()
```

Setting session timezone to UTC is the best solution to avoid conversion, see accepted answer. If for some reason you can't control session timezone because it is being set in high level framework, and you are writing SQL code only, then you can check current_timezone and convert conditionally like this:

```
case when current_timezone() <> 'UTC' 
                 then to_utc_timestamp(from_unixtime(1695773049), current_timezone()) 
            else from_unixtime(1695773049)
 end as smart_conversion --smart conversion back to UTC if we are not in UTC
```