# Spark spark.sql.session.timeZone doesn't work with JSON source

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-2.3

*Does Spark v2.3.1 depends on local timezone when reading from JSON file?*

My `src/test/resources/data/tmp.json`:

```
[
  {
    "timestamp": "1970-01-01 00:00:00.000"
  }
]
```

and Spark code:

```java
SparkSession.builder()
    .appName("test")
    .master("local")
    .config("spark.sql.session.timeZone", "UTC")
    .getOrCreate()
    .read()
    .option("multiLine", true).option("mode", "PERMISSIVE")
    .schema(new StructType()
        .add(new StructField("timestamp", DataTypes.TimestampType, true, Metadata.empty())))
    .json("src/test/resources/data/tmp.json")
    .show();
```

Result:

```
+-------------------+
|          timestamp|
+-------------------+
|1969-12-31 22:00:00|
+-------------------+
```

*How to make spark return `1970-01-01 00:00:00.000`?*

**P.S.** This question is not a duplicate of [Spark Strutured Streaming automatically converts timestamp to local time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48767008/spark-strutured-streaming-automatically-converts-timestamp-to-local-time), because provided there solution not work for me and is already included (see `.config("spark.sql.session.timeZone", "UTC")`) into my question.

Comment: Could you confirm that `org.apache.spark.sql.RuntimeConfig` actually reflects the configuration? Does the other solution fix the problem?

Comment: Actually nevermind. Setting `user.timezone` does solve the problem. As of this it qualifies for JIRA ticket, if there isn't one already. The behavior is not only confusing, but also inconsistent between different data sources.

Comment: @user6910411 solved with `TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"))`

Comment: That however, wont' help you in a distributed mode.

Comment: @user6910411 yeah, good point

Comment: I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48767250/6910411) is still the best approach here. And `spark.sql.session.timeZone` affects only SQL code it might be a good idea to set it anyway, to ensure consistent results.