# Pyspark - from_unixtime not showing the correct datetime

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, timestamp, apache-spark-sql

I want to convert the timestamp column which contains epoch time into datetime (human readable). `from_unixtime` is not giving me the correct date and time. Please help.

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([('1535934855077532656',), ('1535934855077532656',),('1535935539886503614',)], ['timestamp',])

df.show()
```

```
+-------------------+
|          timestamp|
+-------------------+
|1535934855077532656|
|1535934855077532656|
|1535935539886503614|
+-------------------+
```

```py
df.withColumn('datetime',from_unixtime(df.timestamp,"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss:SSS")).select(['timestamp','datetime']).show(15,False)
```

```
+-------------------+----------------------------+
|timestamp          |datetime                    |
+-------------------+----------------------------+
|1535934855077532656|153853867-12-24 10:24:31:872|
|1535934855077532656|153853867-12-24 10:24:31:872|
|1535935539886503614|153875568-09-17 05:33:49:872|
+-------------------+----------------------------+
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`from_unix_time`

> Converts the number of seconds from unix epoch (1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC) to a string
>   representing the timestamp of that moment in the current system time zone in the given
>   format.

Your data is clearly not expressed with seconds. Maybe nanoseconds?

```
 from pyspark.sql.functions import col, from_unixtime


df.withColumn(
    'datetime',
   from_unixtime(df.timestamp / 1000 ** 3,"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss:SSS")
).show(truncate=False)

# +-------------------+-----------------------+
# |timestamp          |datetime               |
# +-------------------+-----------------------+
# |1535934855077532656|2018-09-03 02:34:15:000|
# |1535934855077532656|2018-09-03 02:34:15:000|
# |1535935539886503614|2018-09-03 02:45:39:000|
# +-------------------+-----------------------+
```

Comment: Thank you for answering. Sorry, i am new to Pyspark. Yes, my timestamp is in nanosecond. Can we get the nano second precision using from_unixtime ? Secondly, how do i get the time in a specific timezone. e.g JST (Japan Time). Thank you

Comment: @Sun You can get at most millisecond output with `date_format((df.timestamp / 1000.0 ** 3).cast("timestamp"), "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss:SSS")` and TZ is determined through configuration ([Spark Strutured Streaming automatically converts timestamp to local time](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48767008/6910411)).