# How to get the current local time or system time in spark-scala dataframe?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, timezone, java-time

I am trying to get the local time in spark-scala but it is returning UTC.

I am using java.time.LocalDateTime to get the current timestamp. But its returning the UTC standard.

```
java.sql.Timestamp.valueOf(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS").format(LocalDateTime.now))
```

The LocalDateTime is returning local time in spark shell, but in my code it is giving UTC standard.

```
val time: LocalDateTime = LocalDateTime.now
```

How to get the current time?

The current output is UTC. I need the local time.
I need to change the zone.

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `Timestamp`. That class is poorly designed and long outdated. Instead use a class from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Answer (score 2):

The best way I know is to use GMT offset based on your timezone.
Get your GMT offset and replace. My GMT offset is -5 in this example. Let me know if it helps.
let me know if his solves the problem.

```
df=spark.sql("select from_utc_timestamp(current_timestamp(),'GMT-5') AS your_local_datetime")
df.show(truncate=False)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `current_timestamp()` in `org.apache.spark.sql.fuctions`, this gives local time.

Comment: Thank you, Yes I have tried that. But that is also returning UTC. Do you know how to config spark to local time?

Comment: if you want to retrieve as dataframe then spark.range(1).select(current_timestamp).show(false) otherwise you can retrive it by    using first like this  "var date_ = spark.range(1).select(current_timestamp).first.get(0)"

Comment: 2019-09-28 15:17:20.079
This is the time returned by this answer (UTC time). My local time is 20:48 now.